# Beamer, page/frame numbers, buttons and Appendix slides

Tags: beamer, hyperref, page-numbering, appendices

I am using `beamer` and I have a slide in an Appendix section. I hyper-reference it with a button. The Appendix does not appear as a section itself. The Appendix material is at the end of the code. I would like all of this to remain.

When I click on the button on Slide 2, it brings me to the Appendix slide. The Appendix Slide says p. 3. Even though the it is linked from Section 2.

Would it be possible to do either of the following two?

1. Have the appendix slide be the same from which it is buttoned. In this case, say 2/3.
2. Have the appendix slide have no page number. Just be blank.

The following code should illustrate the point.

```
\documentclass[professionalfont]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{}

\frame
{
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 1
\hspace{0.01cm}\hyperlink{eaa<1>}{\beamergotobutton{Literature}}
}

\frame
{
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 2
\hspace{0.01cm}\hyperlink{eab<1>}{\beamergotobutton{Literature}}
}

\frame
{
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 3
}

\section*{}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\frame[label=eaa]
{
\frametitle{Appendix Material}
Appendix Material here for Slide 1.
{
{\tiny

\hfill\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\beamerreturnbutton{}}

}}
}


\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\frame[label=eab]
{
\frametitle{Appendix Material}
Appendix Material here for Slide 2.
{
{\tiny

\hfill\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\beamerreturnbutton{}}

}}
}

\end{document}
```

I would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one way to *remove* the slide numbering from the Appendix slide, via the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). The idea being that you replace the insertion of the frame in the `footline` template with a `\phantom` version of itself:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 2
\hspace{0.01cm}\hyperlink{eab<1>}{\beamergotobutton{Literature}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 3
\end{frame}

\section*{}

% Remove <frame #> / <total frame #> from footline template
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@footline}% <cmd>
  {\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber}% <search>
  {\phantom{\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber}}% <replace>
  {}% <success>
  {}% <failure>
\makeatother

\begin{frame}[label=eab]
\frametitle{Appendix Material}
Appendix Material here.
{\tiny\hfill\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\beamerreturnbutton{}}}
\end{frame}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}% Correct total frame count
\end{document}
```

The [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) `footline` template is stored in `beamer@@tmpl@footline`. It's just easier replacing (or patching) the necessary commands rather than redefining it all over again.

---

A similar approach can be used to *repeat* the frame number of some other slide. One way is to "capture" the frame number in a different counter, and then patch the `footline` to display that number rather than the regular `framenumber` counter (via `\insertframenumber`). Here is a complete minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lmodern
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcounter{captureframe}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 2
\hspace{0.01cm}\hyperlink{eab<1>}{\beamergotobutton{Literature}}
\end{frame}
\setcounter{captureframe}{\value{framenumber}}% Store/capture current frame

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 3
\end{frame}

\section*{}

% Replace <frame #> in footline template
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@footline}% <cmd>
  {\insertframenumber}% <search>
  {\thecaptureframe}% <replace>
  {}% <success>
  {}% <failure>
\makeatother

\begin{frame}[label=eab]
\frametitle{Appendix Material}
Appendix Material here.
{\tiny\hfill\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\beamerreturnbutton{}}}
\end{frame}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}% Correct total frame count
\end{document}
```

The frame number is captured via

```
\setcounter{captureframe}{\value{framenumber}}
```

after defining the new counter `captureframe`. In the patch to the `footline` template, `\insertframenumber` is replaced with `\thecaptureframe` (which defaults to an `\arabic` presentation of the counter).

Both of the above solutions will impact all slides/frames following the patch. So, if a modification should be made temporarily, some more work is required (but is not difficult).

---

Based on certain assumptions, an elementary method using macros (that does not require `etoolbox`) can be established to reference slides. The assumptions are

1. There is a clear separation between "frontmatter" and "backmatter" slides. The former contain slides that could be "referenced" while the latter contains the "referenced" slides.
2. Manual usage of certain macros are required before *every* "backmatter" slide in order to maintain an accurate count of the total frame number.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lmodern
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\saveframenumber}[1]{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname r@#1\endcsname{\theframenumber}% Store frame number
}
\newcommand{\useframenumber}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}% Decrease framenumber counter
  \renewcommand{\insertframenumber}{%
    \csname r@#1\endcsname%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\restoreframenumberdefault}{%
  \renewcommand{\insertframenumber}{%
    \arabic{framenumber}%
  }%
}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 2
\hspace{0.01cm}\hyperlink{eab<1>}{\beamergotobutton{Literature}}
\end{frame}
\saveframenumber{myslide}% Save this slide number as <myslide>

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 3
\end{frame}

\section*{}

\useframenumber{myslide}% Use the same number as on <myslide>
\begin{frame}[label=eab]
\frametitle{Appendix Material}
Appendix Material here.
{\tiny\hfill\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\beamerreturnbutton{}}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The usage is:

- After a slide that you want to reference in the "backmatter", you place `\saveframenumber{<name>}`. This stores the value of the current frame in `\r@<name>`.
- Before *every* "backmatter" slide that uses the "referenced" slide in the "frontmatter", you place `\useframenumber{<name>}`.

Comment: I can't get that code to compile. :(  Your original code compiles.  It excludes the page number in the Appendix like you designed.  However, this new code does not seem to work.  I would be very grateful if you could please help with that.

Comment: @JG: You probably did not copy the entire code. In the preamble I define a new counter: `\newcounter{captureframe}`. Did you include that? If you did and you still cannot compile the code, please report the error that you receive, since it compiles fine on my end.

Comment: Here is the error.  It stops compiling at this point.  LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 15.


SyncTeX warning: Synchronization was disabled from
the command line with -synctex=0
Changing the value of \synctex has no effect.[1{C:/Documents and Settings/Local Settings/Application Data/MiKTeX/2.9
/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] [2]
> \insertframenumber=macro:
->\@arabic \c@framenumber .
l.24 \show\insertframenumber
                            
?

Comment: @JG: I've updated my answer to correct for the missing font size (using [`lmodern`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lm)). There was also a `\show\insertframenumber` left from the initial debugging procedure which has been removed. Note that I only received warnings, which is not the same as errors. See the [revision history](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/44177/revisions) for the exact changes to the answer.

Comment: The code compiles, and it is absolutely brilliant!  Brilliant!!  However, I cannot understand how I would replicate it.  Suppose I had a second frame in the Appendix say for Slide 1.  How would I get that frame to say 1/3 but this appendix one to say 2/3.

Comment: @JG: If you know the exact frame that it is on, you can hard-code the reference (or use an actual `\label` and `\ref`). For hard-coding, I would do `\makeatletter\patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@footline}{\insertframenumber}{<n>}{}{}\makeatother` where `<n>` is the frame number that you want to duplicate for that specific slide. `beamer`'s `footline` is setup to be automated, and such "abnormal" requests require manual intervention. So, that's why you are required to persistently modify it where you may need it. Hopefully there aren't very many of them.

Comment: I'm not following what you are saying.  I would gladly to \label and \ref.  I don't quite see how to implement this.  I don't see how to implement the hard-coding either.  I'd rather have it automated.  I do have several of these.  I'm willing to do whatever work it takes.  I would rather have it automated only in case the presentation material were to change around.  I edited the above post to reflect a second appendix slide for the First Slide.  Would you please so kindly update your code to reflect that?

Comment: This is an amazingly good answer!  This answer deserves thousands of bounty points!!  Everybody please give points to werner.  Werner was so generous with his/her time.  Wrote amazing code.  Simply beyond the call of duty.  I wish I had thousands of points to bounty.

Answer (score 7):

Thid is only a solution for an empty pagecounter for the appendix:
Define an empty footline for the appendix:

```
[ ... ]
\section*{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{frame}[label=eab]
\frametitle{Appendix Material}
Appendix Material here.
{\tiny\hfill\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\beamerreturnbutton{}}}
\end{frame}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\end{document}
```

if you want the same style of the footnote then redefine it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\def\resetFootline#1{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 2
\hspace{0.01cm}\hyperlink{eab<1>}{\beamergotobutton{Literature}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide Title}
Slide 3
\end{frame}

\section*{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\leavevmode\hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~(\insertshortinstitute)
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}\vskip0pt}

\begin{frame}[label=eab]
\frametitle{Appendix Material}
Appendix Material here.
{\tiny\hfill\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\beamerreturnbutton{}}}
\end{frame}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Herbert.  I am very curious about your answer.  I don't know if the OP understands it.  But I cannot.  Is it like the answer above that it deletes the page number?  Does it set the page number to be the pages from which it is referenced (e.g. page 2 per the OP's question and example)?

Comment: @Jes: The redefinition of the `footline` template does not have a `\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber` construct in it, so `# / ##` is not displayed in the footer. For example, see [How can I remove the institute from the author footline on beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35175/5764) that shows a similar `footline` construction *with* `# / ##`.

Comment: @Werner.  I don't understand what you mean.  In any event, I cannot tell which of these codes would set the slide number to be 2 in the appendix.  Both seem to set them to be blank, which is an option I'd be ok with.  My preferred option is to set it at page 2.  Please let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @JG: Herbert's code removes the slide numbering and that's that. The linked post in the my other comment just shows the comparison of creating a `footline` template that has the slide numbering in it. If you compare the two, you'll see the one has `\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber` and the other (this one) doesn't.

Comment: @Hebert.  Wonderful answer.  Thank you very much for taking the time to help!