# Avoiding page numbers in allowframebreaks option - beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, page-numbering

In my presentation, I am citing many papers and thus want to have a bibliography in the end so that people can refer to full citations as well. But I don't want to include them in page numbers in presentation(not to scare the audience). Any clean solution for this?

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\scriptsize{\bibliographystyle{acm}}
\bibliography{references}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Give the full bibliography in a handout, not in the presentation.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for the suggestion, but I am looking for a latex oriented solution :)

Comment: This should work for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44132/beamer-page-frame-numbers-buttons-and-appendix-slides